# Как в Yii2 сделать пагинацию с многоточием?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Может кто делал уже что то подобное и может подсказать как для GridView прикрутить пагинацию вида [1] [2] [3] [4] ... [12] ?

Comment: Получив необходимые данные с помощью [ActiveDataProvider](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/output-data-providers.md), в том числе и данные пагинации, вы можете что угодно сделать. Дело в том, что вы фреймворк воспринимаете, как CMS. Виджетов на манер `GridView` там может и не быть.

Comment: Да, согласен с предыдущим замечанием. Однако, в документации yii2 есть описание подобных возможностей. Сам этим не пользовался, но нашел вот это: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-baselistview.html#$pager-detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте данное расширение https://github.com/justinvoelker/yii2-separatedpager